# Automatically calling action AFTER redux state is loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a app in which users can build a "Quote".  So far I've been adhering to "idiomatic" redux (or something close to it) and it's been working out well.

However, I'm struggling to deal with a fairly simple scenario:

When the page is first opened, I fire an async `LOAD` event which retrieves info from the server needed to build the quote (products, inventory, previously saved line items, etc).

I need some way to be able to automatically add a specific line item(s) to the quote first it's first opened.

I've added a `defaultLineItems` property to my `LOAD` payload, but to fire the `addLineItem(product, inventory, options)` action, I need data from the `productReducer`, `inventoryReducer`, `optionsReducer`.  The `lineItemReducer` could look at these `defaultLineItems` and try to set it's state appropriately, but that would require having to rewrite a lot of BL typically handled by the actions using data aggregated from reducer memorized "selectors" (EG: defaulting price, quantity, currency translation, etc)

I can think of a couple ways to achieve this, but they all seem somewhat hack-ish (IE storing a flag in the reducer that says I need to fire an action and then running it when my root component props update).  It seems like a react component should not be responsible for this type thing.

What is the proper way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are a couple different ways this can be accomplished but for me the most balanced approach between simplicity and design was to use [store.subscribe](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe(listener)) in conjunction with a reducer to track the last action(s).

At it's simplest, this would look something like this.

```
store.subscribe(function() {
  let state = store.getState();
  if(state.lastAction.type === ActionKeys.LOAD){
    console.log('load action fired!');
  }
})
```

Please be aware that firing an action from `store.subscribe` will cause recursion so you need to be selective.